# PostgreSQL password authentication failed for user "user"

Tags: windows, postgresql, authentication, sequelize.js, postgresql-10

I have tried to Google this question for a long time now, and I do not seem to get to a solution.

I have downloaded PostgreSQL on Windows, and therefore have a user with `username: postgres` and `password: postgres`.

I have no problem with connection using the command line: `psql -U postgres`.

The problem is when I try to just log in through `psql` or by using an api with `npm run start`. I tried setting `PG_URL=postgres://postgres:postgres@localhost/postgres`, since I am using it in this api.

I then get the error message: `psql: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "username on my windows computer"`.

I have not used my username on the computer at all when setting up this database or server, so I do not know what to do. And when I try to log in through psql none of the password I can think of is correct.

[This is how the pgAdmin4 page looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uatUx.png)

Comment: Struggling with the same issue — have you been able to figure out the cause?

Comment: Realizing this is almost two years later -- were you ever able to solve this problem? One thing that jumps out is that the working option `psql -U postgres` omits a password; depending on your pg_hba.conf configuration, your server could be set up to reject password based authentication, but allow other authentication methods like trust (https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/auth-pg-hba-conf.html, `auth_method` section).

Answer (score 1):

Faced the exact same problem and the answer provided here solved it [solution](https://superuser.com/questions/1278748/postgresql-on-windows-psql-expects-me-to-log-in-with-my-windows-account). Just run set PGUSER=postgres in the command prompt and the next time u run psql the password you enter for username=postgres should work.